# Improve TwiddleCase function to work in visual block mode

Tags: vim

The following snippet can be found on the [vim wiki:](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Switching_case_of_characters)

```
function! TwiddleCase(str)
  if a:str ==# toupper(a:str)
    let result = tolower(a:str)
  elseif a:str ==# tolower(a:str)
    let result = substitute(a:str,'\(\<\w\+\>\)', '\u\1', 'g')
  else
    let result = toupper(a:str)
  endif
  return result
endfunction
vnoremap ~ ygv"=TwiddleCase(@")<CR>Pgv
```

This, however, fails in visual block mode. Given the following
input:

```
foo alpha
bar beta
```

Having the cursor positioned on the `f` of `foo` and pressing
<kbd>ctrl-v</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>~</kbd> yields the following result.

```
Foo
Bar alpha
 beta
```

instead of the expected

```
Foo alpha
Bar beta
```

How can this function be improved to properly work in visual block mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the use of the *expression register* (`"=`) forces a *characterwise* operation.

To fix that, manipulate the default register (that contains the original yanked text, anyway), and keep the original register type via `getregtype()`:

```
vnoremap ~ y:call setreg('', TwiddleCase(@"), getregtype(''))<CR>gv""Pgv
```

Comment: This fails if `clipboard=unnamed` is set. Case twiddling in visual mode doesn't work at all.

Comment: I just fixed your complaint; I didn't say it's perfect :-) Also, the default register shouldn't be clobbered; it should be saved and restored. When you do that, you can do the same to `'clipboard'`, too.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that. What did you fix? You didn't update the code, did you?

Comment: I did right now; explicitly using the unnamed register via `""` fixes the problem. But note that there are at least two more potential problems.

Comment: Thanks for the update and the quick answer in the first place. Seems to work now. If I encounter further problems I'll tune it as necessary, but for now I leave it like it is.